# Composing a script in Powershell V3

Tags: string, powershell-3.0

I would like to know how i can create a script using powershell v3 to obtain the names of all the SQL instances. for example Environment 23Dev would have two virtual boxes. ASNAV-DEVSQL-23
and ASNAV-DEVWEB-23. I want to return the info ASNVA-DEVSQL-23 all the way up to Environment 50?

Can anyone assist with this?

Regards,

Joe

Comment: it is very unclear what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

here is an example that will list sql instance of SQLSERVER1 and SQLSERVER2 :

```
"SQLSERVER1","SQLSERVER2" | % {
    invoke-command -computername $_ -scriptblock{
        "SERVER $env:computername"
        (get-itemproperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server').InstalledInstances 
    }
}
```

Comment: hi kayasax, thanks for the response. this command line below is error on my powershell prompt   (get-itemproperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server').Install it states that it doesnt exist

Comment: @wessun007 sorry to ask, but you have replaced sqlserver1 & 2 with your servers name right ?

Comment: are you able to check in the registry if that key exist anyway ?

Comment: is winrm running on these sqlservers ? could you write the complete code and error received  ?

Comment: SERVER ASNAV-DEVWEB-23                                                                                                                
Cannot find path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQL Server' because it does not exist.

Comment: Cannot find path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQL Server' because it does not exist.

Comment: + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQL Server:String) [Get-ItemProperty], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand
    + PSComputerName        : ASNAV-DEVWEB-23

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner will list all your local instances in the form of a PowerShell object:

```
[System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator]::Instance.GetDataSources() | Format-Table -Auto
```

Taken from: http://tangodude.wordpress.com/2014/02/07/list-local-sql-server-instances-with-powershell/

Edit:

This bit of code should work better than the previous one:

```
$Current = Get-Location;
Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking;
Set-Location $Current;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoApplication]::EnumAvailableSqlServers()
```

Edit:

This is using WMI to query the services on the target computer.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement") | Out-Null;

$MC = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer("COMPUTER_NAME_HERE");
foreach ($Instance in ($MC.Services | Where-Object { $_.Type -Eq "SqlServer" }))
{
    Write-Host $Instance.Name;
}
```

Comment: it only works properly with local instances. if you're trying to locate remote instances (even if they are just local VMs), I've just edited the answer with another bit of code.

Comment: hi tango, the above script doesnt return anything in my ConEmu powershell window?

Comment: can you try [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoApplication]::EnumAvailableSqlServers("<your_vm_name_here>") to see if you can query a specific machine?

Comment: still no output? [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoApplication]::EnumAvailableSqlServers("<y‌ MIM-ICEWEB-72>")

Comment: Like this, without the <> around the name: [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoApplication]::EnumAvailableSqlServers("MIM-ICEWEB-72")

Comment: still nothing on the output.

Comment: curious. can you even ping those vm's? and if so, can you even use SSMS to connect to their SQL Server instances, from the computer you're running powershell?

Comment: i can ping those vm's i connect to them via remote desktop manager from my pc

Comment: but can you connect to their SQL Server instances via SSMS, from the same computer you're running the script? Asking this because if even SSMS can't see them, powershell won't fare any better.

Comment: I dont have SSMS installed on any of the VM's

Comment: sorry SSMS is installed on all the vm's

Comment: I can connect to any environment using SSMS.

Comment: Hmm, you're making roll my sleeves here. Just edited the answer with another option. If this won't show you what's running on the target computer, I don't know what will.